# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define

Tags: android, eclipse

ALL,

I am trying to modify someone else's code to fix the bugs.
I identified that in order to fix one bug I need to upgrade one third party library.

I downloaded new SDK from their web site, then opened the Windows Explorer. There I opened the directory /libs and renamed the old SDK .jar, then copied the new SDK .jar to this place.

Next I opened Eclipse modified the code in compliance with the new SDK fixing all compile issues and finally tried to execute the code on the actual device (I have HTC Android phone).

At this point I got the error message showing in the "Subject" line.
I tried to delete the project copy it to another location and "Import" it again. This didn't fix it.

I didn't upgrade anything (like Android SDK or FB SDK). All I did was to upgrade some Ad library/SDK from some very old version to the newer one.

If this sounds familiar and you know a way to fix this error, please share.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently removing an old copy of the library completely did solve the problem.

However this shouldn't be necessary as the project links only with the new version....

And Eclipse referencing only one file which is newer version of SDK.

Anyway, thank you to people who read this and hopefully it will help someone else.

Thank you.